# DataGridView - how freeze a column?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Using DataGridView with VB.Net 2008.
I would like to freeze the left column so that when/if scrolled this column still remains in place.
can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- [How to: Freeze Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e9w2e1.aspx):

  > **To freeze a column programmatically**
  >
  > Set the `DataGridViewColumn.Frozen` property to `true`:
  >
  > ```
  > Me.dataGridView1.Columns("AddToCartButton").Frozen = True
  > ```
- [How to: Freeze Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control Using the Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/717ss6s6.aspx):

  > **To freeze a column using the designer**
  >
  > 1. Click the smart tag glyph on the upper-right corner of the `DataGridView` control, and then select *Edit Columns*.
  > 2. Select a column from the Selected Columns list.
  > 3. In the Column Properties grid, set the `Frozen` property to `true`.

Comment: +1 for delivering that seemingly obvious answer without bashing the poster :)